# AVD emulator is not starting

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I must have done something but don't know what. I was happily programming away when I started playing with the 9patch tool. And then something happened to stop the AVD running. I did everything - uninstalled Eclipse, SDK, JDK, reinstalled it all (a few times!), and still the same error. I use Eclipse 1.3.2, SDK with r20, JDK 7. I looked at everyone's answers but nothing helped. When everything was working and I started the AVD manager I would get the 'black boxes' of the batch files flashing away as it started so I knew everything was okay. But now I don't get that. I get the dialog box below. Does anyone have any idea? I'm on the verge of giving up!

Starting emulator for AVD 'first'
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sat on this for days and then with a friend who spotted the problem. In my main Linearlayout of the main xml I deleted these two lines:
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

I still get the error warnings above, but the project uploads and runs.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem, but I don't think it comes from your code.
In my case, I just start it without starting/running  any project.